# Should order of epics matter?

Tags: redux-observable

In my code the order of epics matter (example below) but my feeling is that it shouldn't so where's the truth?

From looking at [the code of combineEpics](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/blob/f632eaae81b1b3d13b6e90687931f1a5863b0e0d/src/combineEpics.js#L6) it looks like epics are called sequentially so technically order matters but should the application behave the same even if the code contained `...epics.reverse().map`?

Thanks

E.g. this behaves differently

```
combineEpics(
  epic1,
  epic2,
);
```

than this

```
combineEpics(
  epic2,
  epic1,
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order you provide the epics reflects the order in which they will receive the latest dispatched action. So order does indeed matter, though in practice I've never seen an app run into a case where it truly did.

I can see contrived cases where it could bite you mostly around epic-to-epic actions, but I haven't heard of anyone hitting them.

[Demo showing order matters](https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-observable-playground-n9fzsd?file=index.js)

---

Even if not likely to affect anyone this is probably something we should mention in the docs since it may not obvious to everyone.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I conclude that the epics _are_ order-dependant but it _shouldn't_ matter and therefore I need to revise how my epics are structured/connected.